# Multiplying 4x3 affine transform matrices in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, math, matrix

I am trying to calculate transforms in Three.JS and honestly I'm new to 3D math.

In Three.JS there is a 3x3 and 4x4 matrix class but no 4x3.

**Goal**: I want to understand how to do multiplication on a 4x3*4x3 matrix.

I have a set of the inputs and the correct outputs. I got it by using python, because there is a library called `Noesis` that has multiplication of 4x3 matrices.

The problem is that the library calls from a python binary, so I can't see the source code.

The code in python is simply: `modelSpaceMat = boneMat * frameMat`

Here is a sample of the **correct** dataset:

```
boneMat= (
 (0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 
 (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 
 (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
 (0.0, 32.29199981689453, -3.2665998935699463)
)
frameMat= (
 (0.6425124406814575, -0.06018795818090439, 0.7639083862304688), 
 (-0.003379624802619219, 0.9966778755187988, 0.08136376738548279), 
 (-0.7662678360939026, -0.05486864596605301, 0.640174925327301), 
 (4.438972473144531, -1.4769394397735596, 3.863013744354248)
)
modelSpaceMat=(
 (-0.7639083862304688, -0.06018795818090439, 0.6425124406814575), 
 (-0.08136376738548279, 0.9966778755187988, -0.003379624802619219), 
 (-0.640174925327301, -0.05486864596605301, -0.7662678360939026), 
 (-1.1457012760729413e-07, 30.441999435424805, 9.592490357590577e-08)
)

boneMat= (
 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
 (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 
 (0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 
 (0.0, 0.007000000216066837, -3.2665998935699463)
)
frameMat= (
 (1.0000004768371582, 2.3320662876358256e-06, -1.4419805665966123e-05), 
 (2.817355607476202e-06, 0.9999991059303284, -3.3202520626218757e-06), 
 (1.5038006495160516e-05, -2.133270072590676e-06, 1.0000003576278687), 
 (-0.0015083501348271966, 0.02300064079463482, 3.266691207885742)
)
modelSpaceMat= (
 (1.0000004768371582, 2.3320662876358256e-06, -1.4419805665966123e-05), 
 (2.817355607476202e-06, 0.9999991059303284, -3.3202520626218757e-06), 
 (1.5038006495160516e-05, -2.133270072590676e-06, 1.0000003576278687), 
 (-0.0014612301019951701, 0.030011480674147606, 9.013115777634084e-05)
)
```

Now I want to be able to do it with javascript.

**Questions**:

- Is there any library available?
- What is the formula?

---

The python module, [Noesis](http://www.richwhitehouse.com/index.php?content=inc_projects.php#prjmp91), has this line:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, (NoeMat43, list, tuple)):
        return noesis.mat43Mul(self, other)
    elif isinstance(other, NoeVec3):
        return noesis.mat43TransformPoint(self, other)
    elif isinstance(other, NoeVec4):
        return noesis.mat43TransformVec4(self, other)
    else:
        return NoeMat43([self.mat43[0]*other, self.mat43[1]*other, self.mat43[2]*other, self.mat43[3]*other])
```

I can't find the source code for `noesis.mat43Mul`.

---

## UPDATE

Testing-out **Tamas Hegedus** answer:

```
var boneMat = new THREE.Matrix4().copy(_bone.userData.modelMatrix);

var frameMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
frameMat.set(
  bone.rotationMatrix[0], bone.rotationMatrix[1], bone.rotationMatrix[2], bone.positionVector[0],
  bone.rotationMatrix[3], bone.rotationMatrix[4], bone.rotationMatrix[5], bone.positionVector[1],
  bone.rotationMatrix[6], bone.rotationMatrix[7], bone.rotationMatrix[8], bone.positionVector[2],
  0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1.0
);

var modelSpaceMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
modelSpaceMat.multiplyMatrices(boneMat, frameMatrix);

console.log(boneMat, frameMat, modelSpaceMat);
```

But the result of this `modelSpaceMat` is a bit different to `modelSpaceMat` of the python library. Like the position part which is `(-1.1457012760729413e-07, 30.441999435424805, 9.592490357590577e-08)` in python but is `3.863013744354248, 30.815059661865234, -7.705572128295898` in javascript.

Why is that?

For reference here are the outputs of the `console.log`:
[image]

Comment: Mathematically you can't multiply a 4x3 matrix by a 4x3 matrix.

Comment: @EliSadoff, thanks, I thought so too. So now I'm confused how the python module is doing it. I'll link to module in the question just incase.

Comment: @majidarif I believe it's doing element-wise multiplication.

Comment: @EliSadoff, what does that mean? Sorry, I'm not too good with math :D

Comment: That means that A * B will give a matrix `((A[0][0]*B[0][0], A[0][1]*B[0][1]...))`.

Comment: @EliSadoff so, like for example, this `(A[3][1]*B[3][1])`: `32.29199981689453*-1.4769394397735596`? but the result is `-47.6933281187` and the correct result I'm expecting is `30.441999435424805`.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))'s a good explanation on it.

Comment: @ the update: Try swapping the factors, in the original form it appears as if the coordinates (x,y,z,1) are multiplied from the left, in the update it appears as if they are multiplied from the right. One of the variants should have at least the rotation part correct.

Comment: @LutzL, how do I swap the factors?

Comment: original  variant: `modelSpaceMat.multiplyMatrices(boneMat, frameMatrix);`, swapped factors: `modelSpaceMat.multiplyMatrices(frameMatrix, boneMat);`. If that is the cause, repair the original formula by changing the matrix construction, either transpose everything if the vector part of the product is correct, or transpose only the rotation part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a mathematical point of view, you cannot multiply 4x3 matrices.

When its about affine transformations, graphics libraries use a special subset of square matrices in the homogeneous space to describe the transformation:

```
a b c 0
d e f 0
g h i 0
x y z 1
```

The last column is chosen to be `0 0 0 1` so the transformation is not a perspective projection.

Some graphics libraries only store the interesting 4x3 portion of that transformation, but multiplication must be done as it was in the 4x4 form.

Threejs has a builtin [`Matrix4`](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Matrix4) class, which implements multiplication.

Comment: Aaah, makes more sense. I updated my question. Can you check? Thanks :)

Comment: @majidarif try to transpose only the rotation part when constructing the threejs matrix

Comment: How would I do that? `frameMat.set(
              bone.rotationMatrix[0], bone.rotationMatrix[3], bone.rotationMatrix[6], bone.positionVector[0],
              bone.rotationMatrix[1], bone.rotationMatrix[4], bone.rotationMatrix[7], bone.positionVector[1],
              bone.rotationMatrix[2], bone.rotationMatrix[5], bone.rotationMatrix[8], bone.positionVector[2],
              0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1.0
            );`

Comment: @majidarif exactly

Comment: Hmmm, by changing the `frameMat` to that. The `modelSpaceMat` is now: `-0.7662678360939026,
-0.003379624802619219,
-0.6425124406814575,
0,
-0.05486864596605301,
0.9966778755187988,
0.06018795818090439,
0,
0.640174925327301,
0.08136376738548279,
-0.7639083862304688,
0,
3.863013744354248,
30.815059661865234,
-7.705572128295898,
1`

Still wrong though, do I also need to transpose the rotation part of `boneMat`?

Comment: @majidarif You might also have to change the multiplication order `modelSpaceMat.multiplyMatrices(frameMatrix, boneMat);`, as `A*B=transposed(transposed(B)*transposed(A))`

Comment: @majidarif and yes, try transposing the rotation part of boneMat too.

Comment: Is this the right way of transposing the rotation part? `boneMat.set(
              boneMat.elements[0], boneMat.elements[1], boneMat.elements[2],  boneMat.elements[12],
              boneMat.elements[4], boneMat.elements[5], boneMat.elements[6],  boneMat.elements[13],
              boneMat.elements[8], boneMat.elements[9], boneMat.elements[10], boneMat.elements[14],
              boneMat.elements[3], boneMat.elements[7], boneMat.elements[11], boneMat.elements[15]
            );`

The result has the position part right, but the rotation part is still wrong (order)

Comment: To get the correct matrix the construction has to use, with high probability, the order `( rot[0], rot[1], rot[2], 0,  rot[3], rot[4], rot[5], 0,  rot[6], rot[7], rot[8], 0,  vec[0], vec[1], vec[2], 1 )`. This supposes that `rot[0,1,2]` and `vec[0,1,2]` are either both rows or both columns in the matrix. `bone*frame` will give a result identical to python if `Threejs.Matrix4` fills rows first, i.e., the first 4 elements are the first row.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Didn't actually need to transpose the `boneMat` rotation. Only the `frameMat`.

Answer (score 0):

[Vektor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vektor) is an NPM package that does vector and matrix maths.

Comment: But still it will not have the multiplication of two 4×3 matrices.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it looks like it has to obey the laws of maths! :-)