# Inverse of a 4x3 matrix in python

Tags: python, math, matrix, inverse

I'm reimplementing a closed source 3d library called noesis.

It exposes a python file with all of the basic classes.

All of the implementation details are actually hidden. The implementation is compiled so I can't preview it.

I want to implement one of the fuctions from that library called mat43Inverse.

I know normally it's not possible to inverse a 4x3 matrix, but this function exists.

Sample usage from a noesis plugin:

```
#4x3 matrix
class NoeMat43:

    # ...

    def inverse(self): #returns mat43
        return noesis.mat43Inverse(self)
```

source of exposed classes file: https://github.com/majimboo/mviewer/blob/master/noesis/plugins/python/inc_noesis.py#L478

noesis module is a compiled cpython module. (https://github.com/majimboo/mviewer/blob/master/noesis/plugins/NoesisPython.dll)

```
boneMtx = NoeMat43((
  NoeVec3((m01, m02, m03)),
  NoeVec3((m11, m12, m13)),
  NoeVec3((m21, m22, m23)),
  NoeVec3((m04, m14, m24))
)).inverse()
```

I prepared a set of correct results by calling the native function and printing the result.

```
input = NoeMat43((
    NoeVec3((2.5, 3.6, 4.7)),
    NoeVec3((2.9, 3.1, 4.3)),
    NoeVec3((6.5, 7.6, 8.7)),
    NoeVec3((1.1, 9.4, 3.2))
))

result = input.inverse()
expected = NoeMat43((
    NoeVec3((0.04392901062965393, 0.05095765367150307, 0.1142154261469841)),
    NoeVec3((0.044815145432949066, 0.038590818643569946, 0.09460975229740143)),
    NoeVec3((0.04042314738035202, 0.036982882767915726, 0.07482582330703735)),
    NoeVec3((-0.8928132057189941, -0.714801549911499, -0.6315471529960632))
))
noeassert('mat43Inverse', result, expected)
```

**Correct results**

1.

```
input: (
(1, 0, 0),
(0, 1, 0),
(0, 0, 1),
(0, 0, 0)
)

inverse result: (
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
)
```

2.

```
input: (
(2.5, 3.6, 4.7),
(2.9, 3.1, 4.3),
(6.5, 7.6, 8.7),
(1.1, 9.4, 3.2)
)

invserse result: (
(0.04392901062965393, 0.05095765367150307, 0.1142154261469841),
(0.044815145432949066, 0.038590818643569946, 0.09460975229740143),
(0.04042314738035202, 0.036982882767915726, 0.07482582330703735),
(-0.8928132057189941, -0.714801549911499, -0.6315471529960632)
)
```

3.

```
input: (
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
(0.0, 32.29199981689453, -3.2665998935699463)
)

inverse result: (
(0.0, 0.0, -1.0),
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
(-3.2665998935699463, -32.29199981689453, 0.0)
)
```

4.

```
input: (
(0.0, 0.0, 2.0),
(0.0, 2.0, 0.0),
(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0),
(0.0, 32.29199981689453, -3.2665998935699463)
)

inverse result: (
(0.0, 0.0, -0.5),
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0),
(0.5, 0.0, 0.0),
(-1.6332999467849731, -16.145999908447266, 0.0)
)
```

5.

```
input: (
(2.0, 0.0, 2.0),
(0.0, 2.0, 0.0),
(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0),
(0.0, 32.29199981689453, -3.2665998935699463)
)

inverse result: (
(0.2499999850988388, 0.0, -0.2499999850988388),
(0.0, 0.5, 0.0),
(0.5, 0.0, 0.0),
(-0.8166499137878418, -16.145999908447266, 0.0)
)
```

**Questions:**

- What is the formula behind mat43Inverse function?

Comment: No idea, but can't you find where the function is stored and open the corresponding file? It's in a python module?

Comment: All of the implementation details are actually hidden. The implementation is compiled so I can't preview it.

Comment: Mathematically, you can only calculate the inverse of a square matrix. Perhaps this function implements a pseudo-inverse or [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse)?

Comment: I'd suggest trying that function on all simpler matrices like truncated identity matrix, identity matrix multiplied by a const, etc. At the very least you will learn about linearity of that function.

Comment: Also, what doe the documentation says and where/how this function is typically used?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563668/multiplying-4x3-affine-transform-matrices-in-javascript

Comment: There is no documentation about this "hidden implementation" method. It's supposed to be called whenever you want to call noeMat43.inverse(). Like in example above.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I know about answer. It relates to mat43Mul function which I have working. This question is about the inverse of 4x3 matrix.

Comment: Added more examples @yeputons

Comment: Since this is a 3d library, it is very likely that the last column is just hidden and assumed to be `(0, 0, 0, 1)`. This assumption is supported by some of your examples but not all of them. Are you sure the values are correct?

Comment: yes, I got them from the official API

Comment: possibly helpful, or not https://github.com/nathanfaucett/cpp-Odin/blob/master/src/mathf/mat43.cpp

Answer (score 5):

As **Nico Schertler** pointed out **4x3** matrix in **3D** graphics is usually **4x4** uniform transform matrix where the last row or column (depends on the convention used) is omitted and represents `(0,0,0,1)` vector (no projection). This is done usually to preserve space.

I am too lazy to check your samples but if results does not match than you most likely got different convention on how the element/cells of the matrix are ordered. To check for correctness just multiply original and inverse matrix (both in full 4x4 representations) and the result should be unit matrix.

There are 3 approaches of how to compute inverse matrix in **3D** graphics I know of:

1. **Horner scheme / GEM Gauss elimination method**

   This is straightforward method usable on paper but in computer computation is this not very good choice as it need a bit sophistication for sorting the rows so the result is still leading to Inverse. That sometimes lead to trial and error which would mean possible performance problems latter on.
2. **Inverse from Determinant**

   This is the best choice for unknown matrices as It need no sorting and is always computable if the matrix has an inverse. There are sometimes accuracy problems if numbers/vectors used have too big magnitudes. Here code in C++ for such (OpenGL convention):

   - [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

   Look for `matrix_inv` function in the code.
3. **Pseudo inverse matrix**

   In some cases you can avoid computing of inverse matrix by determinants or Horner scheme / Gauss elimination method because in some cases you can exploit the fact that `Transpose` of **orthogonal rotational matrix** is also its `inverse`. So the computations boils down to simple tranpose of 3x3 matrix (just swapping elements) and computing linear equation to match the inverse matrix origin. That is much much less computations hence better accuracy and speed. Here is how it is done (OpenGL convention):

   - [How to preserve accuracy with cumulative transforms over time (full pseudo inverse matrix)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293434/2521214)

   look for bullet **#3** there.